# jQuery isn't creating table row elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a JavaScript progress bar and the bar itself and the detail message are inside a table. Now, I'm creating this so that all that needs to be in the page is a `div` and then the class will fill in the rest when it's created. Since it's in a table, the bar and message are supposed to be on different rows, however when I try to create the rows with jQuery they aren't getting generated and the only thing that is getting put in the tables is the two `td` elements.

The code I currently have is down below. I've tried several different methods to accomplish it that I thought would work.

- I have tried using `.wrap('<tr></tr>')` to try and get it before I put it in the table, and in the call for the table too (i.e. `tdMessage.wrap('<tr></tr>')` and `tdMessage.wrap('<tr></tr>').html()`).
- I have tried both `document.createElement('tr')` and just `$('<tr></tr>')` and calling `.html()` when putting it in the table.

I feel like there was another attempt in there too...but I can't think of what it was.

```
var tdMessage = $(document.createElement('td'));
tdMessage.prop('id', this.MessageId.substr(1));
tdMessage.css('text-align', 'center');
//tdMessage.wrap('<tr></tr>');
//var trRow2 = $(document.createElement('tr'));
var trRow2 = $('<tr></tr>');
trRow2.html(tdMessage);
tdMessage = null;

var divBar = $(document.createElement('div'));
divBar.prop('id', this.BarId.substr(1));
divBar.css('width', '0%');
divBar.css('height', '15px');
divBar.css('background', 'url(images/LoadingBarBG.gif)');

var tdBar = $(document.createElement('td'));
tdBar.css('border', '1px #B0B1B1 solid');
tdBar.css('padding', '1px');
tdBar.html(divBar);
//tdBar.wrap('<tr></tr>');
divBar = null;

//var trRow1 = $(document.createElement('tr'));
var trRow1 = $('<tr></tr>');
trRow1.html(tdBar);
tdBar = null;

var tblInner = $(document.createElement('table'));
tblInner.prop('width', '400');
tblInner.prop('cellpadding', '0');
tblInner.prop('cellspacing', '0');
tblInner.prop('border', '0');
tblInner.html(trRow1.html() + trRow2.html());
trRow1 = null;
trRow2 = null;
```

I'm probably just missing something, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. Everything looks like it should work, and everything else seems to be.

Also, the HTML that it keeps generating is either just putting both `td` elements in the table without the `tr` elements surrounding them or it will even just put the bars `td` and omit the message one.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `.html()` because everything you have is a jQuery object, not raw HTML, instead append the cell to the row:

```
trRow2.append(tdMessage);

trRow1.append(tdBar);
```

Then append the rows to the table:

```
tblInner
    .append(trRow1)
    .append(trRow2);
```

Do the same with your div when you want to insert it into the cell:

```
tdBar.append(divBar);
```

Comment: I thought the only difference between `.html()` and `.append()` was that `.html()` replaced all existing html inside and that `.append()` just appended it below what was there. Is that not right?

Comment: No that's not right. `.html()` only accepts a string of HTML, it doesn't accept objects. `.append()` accepts objects or HTML. If you were to pass a string to `.html()` then it would destroy and replace all yes.

Comment: Oh, okay. I gotcha. So, if I was to use `.html()` I would have to do something like `trRow1.html(tdBar.html());`?

Comment: Yes but when you get the html of the tdBar it is the inner HTML, not including the `<td></td>` so you need to wrap if you do it like that.

Comment: Yup, I just saw that. Thank ya very much.